The letter 'w' stopped working in Kubuntu Linux - Reason was using key '§' as a shortcut in Yakuake
My small letter 'w' stopped working - the capital 'W' did work alright.
It turns out that this happened because I used the letter '§' as a shortcut for opening and closing Yakuake window, and for some peculiar reason it caused letter 'w' to stop working.
How can this be so?
P.S. I tested two different keyboards with the same result.

Is this repeatable, i.e. if you remap § as your shortcut key does w stop working again?

Have you considered reporting this as a bug to the maintainers of the Yakuake software? Someone else seems to have encountered something similar, but didn't provide necessary detail for the bug to be reproduced

The machine is an iMac, and It is repeatable, indeed. I just remembered that I have an old HP laptop in which I use § as a shortcut for Yakuake and which does not have this issue, so this may be Apple related.
